# cannot run java application from a shell script

Tags: bash, java

after download and unzip the zip package, I copy the modelsphere.bat file to modelsphere.sh, and change the content to:

```
 java -ms64m -mx512m -ss16m -classpath "./modelsphere.jar:./resources.zip:./resources:./targets:./lib/jakarta-regexp-1.5/jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar:./lib/velocity-1.6.1/velocity-1.6.1.jar:./lib/jazzy-core/jazzy-core.jar:./lib/jython-2.2.1/jython.jar:./lib/velocity-1.6.1/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:./lib/velocity-1.6.1/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:./lib/lablib-checkboxtree-3.0.2.jar" org.modelsphere.sms.Application
```

but when running the modelsphere.sh with the command "./modelsphere.sh",  following exception is thrown:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/modelsphere/sms/Application
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.modelsphere.sms.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
.  Program will exit.in class: org.modelsphere.sms.Application
```

when I run the command,

```
java -ms64m -mx512m -ss16m -classpath "./modelsphere.jar:./resources.zip:./resources:./targets:./lib/jakarta-regexp-1.5/jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar:./lib/velocity-1.6.1/velocity-1.6.1.jar:./lib/jazzy-core/jazzy-core.jar:./lib/jython-2.2.1/jython.jar:./lib/velocity-1.6.1/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:./lib/velocity-1.6.1/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:./lib/lablib-checkboxtree-3.0.2.jar" org.modelsphere.sms.Application
```

which is the content of the "modelsphere.sh" file, it works.

why? and how could I start Open ModelSphere with the shell file of "modelsphere.sh"?

Could anyone give me any point? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It probably has DOS line endings (\r\n instead of \n). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/052

And for good practice, you should make sure the first line of the file says `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: to see if it has DOS end-of-lines: shell> cat -vt modelsphere.sh (and look for ^M at the end).  To fix, run "dos2unix  modelsphere.sh" (or tofrodos utils, or just edit the file & remove the ^M)..